# Setting display to none remove the svg element from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jointjs

Setting display to none using jquery or javascript removes the svg element off the DOM. This is strange.

I am trying show a pop up dialog with ok and cancel buttons using jquery which works, but after clicking any of the buttons its deleting the whole svg element from DOM

Code:

```
<div id="dialog" class="bs-example web_dialog">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="left: 173px; top: 258px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; overflow: visible; border: 1px solid #C5C5C5">
                <label for="inputEmail">Unique Id/Mobile Number:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Unique Id" width="10px">
                <label for="inputPassword">Document URL</label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="URL">
                <br>
                <div class="btn-sm">
                    <button type="submit" id="btn_save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ok</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="btn_cancel" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  onclick="closePopUp(event)">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<button type="submit" id="btn_cancel" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  onclick="closePopUp()">Cancel</button>

function closePopUp()
{
    document.getElementById('dialog').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Executing the above is removing svg element off the DOM

Comment: Can you post the element in question?

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, especially the **whole** element  with id=dialog this can not be answered

Comment: Wrap it up in a Div.

Comment: @Java_User Updated the question

Comment: @JaromandaX Updated the question

Comment: there's no SVG there at all

Comment: is it possible that there is some other element with id=dialog?

Comment: How can you tell that it's removing the SVG element?

Comment: @JaromandaX  SVG is generated using javascript library(jointjs)

Comment: and where is it inserted into the DOM?

Comment: @JaromandaX ok give me ten mins I have to make a sample to upload into question as the code is huge

Comment: oh, wait ... the button is a submit button - that'll reload the page ... wont it? forms like this confuse me, why have a form if you aren't submitting anything (I know, this is probably cut down code)

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess you are right. I don't actually have a form. I am just trying to save the svg diagram on button click using pop dialog

Comment: @JaromandaX So just have a anchor tag instead of button?

Comment: just a button, not a submit button, and no form

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right. It fixed the issue. If you post it as answer I will accept it. Thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pressing a submit button in a form is the problem. even though the form element has none of the usual attributes for a form attribute, pressing a submit button will reload the page

option 1: don't use  unless you are submitting data

option 2: return false in the submit buttons onclick

go with option 1 every time :p